# Copiar valor de columna x en y si existe en y en pandas usando Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Quisiera ver una manera de hacer que en un DataFrame usando pandas con Python como la siguiente:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| a | a |
| a | NaN |
| b | NaN |
| c | NaN |
| d | d |

Se copien los valores de la columna `x` en la columna *`y`* en su posición respectiva solo si existen en la *`y`*, por ejemplo, el valor `a` existe en la columna *`y`* entonces se copiaría de la `x` a esa misma, mientas que lo mismo no sucedería en `b` y `c` porque no existen en `y`.

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entendí correctamente, lo que pretendes sería el resultado de:

1. Determinar qué valores distintos de `NaN` aparecen en la columna `y`. Llamemos `validos` al conjunto con esos valores. En tu ejemplo, el conjunto `validos` contendría los elementos "a" y "d"
2. Para todas las filas para las cuales el valor que hay en la columna x esté en el conjunto `validos`, copiar el valor de la columna x a la columna y.

Esto puede implementarse bastante literalmente en la forma siguiente:

```
# Determinar el conjunto de "validos"
validos = set(df.y.dropna().unique())

# Asignar a la columna y el valor de la columna x, pero solo para
# las filas en las que x está en "validos"
df.loc[df.x.isin(validos), "y"] = df.x
```

### Demo

Si el dataframe de entrada es este:

```
   x    y
0  a    a
1  a  NaN
2  b  NaN
3  c  NaN
4  d    d
```

el dataframe resultante será este:

```
   x    y
0  a    a
1  a    a
2  b  NaN
3  c  NaN
4  d    d
```

### Alguna explicación adicional

`df.y.dropna()` se queda solo con los elementos no-NaN de la columna `y`, y aplicando después `.unique()` al resultado se eliminan duplicados. El resultado de eso es una lista, pero mediante `set()` lo convierto a un conjunto porque las búsquedas en conjuntos son más eficientes.

`df.x.isin(validos)` es una función que retorna una columna de booleanos, con el valor `True` únicamente en las filas en las que el valor de `x` esté en el conjunto `validos`. Al usarlo dentro de `.loc[]` nos seleccionará sólamente las filas que queremos cambiar. El segundo parámetro de `.loc[]` es `"y"`, el nombre de la columna en la que queremos escribir.

En el otro lado de la asignación podemos poner directamente `df.x`, y sólo se asignarán las filas seleccionadas en el lado izquierdo, no es necesario volver a aplicar filtros en el lado derecho.

Comment: A mi se me había ocurrido `df.loc[~df.y.isnull(),'y'] = df.x`

Comment: @LucasDamian pero no es eso lo que pide. Imagina que en la fila de índice 2 en vez de un NaN hay una 'a'. Tu mecanismo sobreescribiría esa 'a' con una 'b' (pues en esa fila no hay NaN), pero mi mecanismo dejaría esa fila como estaba, porque en la columna x hay una b, y no hay "b"s en la columna y.

Answer (score 1):

Basada en [esta otra respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43839171/13636459), puedes agrupar según la columna 'x'. Luego llenar los datos para cada agrupación con `group.ffill()`.

```py
df.groupby('x').ffill()

# Resultado:

#    y
#    0  a
#    1  a
#    2  NaN
#    3  NaN
#    4  d
```

Solo hace falta asignar este resultado para remplazar la columna 'y':

```py
df['y']=df.groupby('x').ffill()
```